# Python subprocess.Popen with quotes and backslash

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, popen

I want to sort a tab separated file through a Python script by calling 'sort' command.
If I use this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["sort", r"-t$'t'", "-k1,2", "input", "-o", "output"]).wait()
```

I get this error:

```
sort: multi-character tab `$\'t\''
```

If I use `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.Popen(["sort", r"-t$'t'", "-k1,2", "input", "-o", "output"], shell=True).wait()
```

The process just hangs.

I would prefer using the first method, without `shell=True`. Any suggestions?

EDIT: The file is huge.

Comment: First, python is good at sorting ... Why not use python to sort it?  Second, what are you expecting `-t` to do there in your sort command?  Is your field separator really `$'t'`?

Comment: You're getting this error because `subprocess` is doing exactly what it's supposed to. Try running `sort "-t$'t'" input` from the shell, and you'll get the exact same error from `sort`.

Comment: Python is good at sorting lists; shelling out to the `sort` program is fine for sorting what may be a very large file.

Comment: @chepner -- Why should the `sort` program do any better than python for large files?  As far as I'm aware, `sort` doesn't do any sort external merge sorting to make it more memory efficient ...

Comment: `sort` certainly works on files that won't fit entirely in main memory (at least, I think I recall sorting files that were larger than my available memory).

Comment: @mgilson `sort` does do external sort for large files.

Comment: @tuxx -- If you say so :)  Based on the comments here, I take back my formal statement ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can create a string with a tab; `$'\t'` is only necessary when you are working directly in the shell.

```
subprocess.Popen(["sort", "-t\t", "-k1,2", "input", "-o", "output"]).wait()
```

Comment: Removed. I didn't bother testing it, and there's no reason here to use a shell to process the command.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call("sort", "-t\t", "-k1,2", "input", "-o", "output"])` could be used here, to raise an exception on error.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call(r"sort -t\t -k1,2 input -o output")`

Looks cleaner - `call` is a higher level function on the subprocess module than "Popen" - and would make your code simpler to read.

Than, probably, while calling an external "sort" may have certain facilities for large files (> the ammout of avaliable memory) - unless you are dealign with those, you are probabley making it wrong.

Unlike shell scripts, Python is self-contained in the sense it can perform most tasks with your data internally instead of passing data through external simple posix programs.

For sorting your file named "input" and haveing the results ready to use in memory, just do:

```
# read the data into a list, one line per item:
data = open("input", "rt").readlines()
# sort it, splitting the line on tab characters and taking the first two as key:
data.sort(key=lambda line: line.split("\t")[:2]

# and "data" contains a sorted list of your lines
```